# How to re-use this table

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I have a `<h:dataTable ...></h:dataTable>` with questions, and above that I have a panelgrid with three commandButtons that are invokes three methods in the backing bean. However this dataTable and filtering-buttons would be useful for me in other pages too so I extracted them to a own file. Then when I need it I include it with a parameter (the backing bean).

However it isn't very DRY to have the same methods in multiple backing beans....so I could make a baseclass and inherit them, but they do not relate by inheritance. So would a better approach be to make a QuestionTableHandler class with these methods, then have a property to this in the backing beans? Or are there other approaches that are better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build `composite components` that allow attaching backing beans methods, etc..

IBM has a [guide](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu2/index.html) on that topic.

EDIT:
You could consider writing a general handler with generics that then call the interface of your actual implementation where required.

Comment: How can this be better, I will still need to implement the methods in each backing bean or do it with inheritance.

Comment: Thank you. But what do you mean? Writing an interface named for instance *QuestionTableHandler* then each backingbean that wants to use the datatable needs to implement this? But if the behaviour is the same in many backingbeans...are there other ways? Inheritance doesn't "fit" because the classes are not related.

Comment: As written. It seems that you have some common logic. You should write some sort of handler for this and pass your actual object to that. This object should use a common interface and provide the specific implementation.

Comment: Okey, so just to be straight: In the backing beans I have a property *private QuestionTableHandler questionTableHandler;* and in the view use *someBackingBean.questionTableHandler.someAction()* right?

Comment: I have to check it. But thinking about it we actually extended it. `public class SomeBackingBean extends QuestionTableHandler<MyImpl>` or something like that.